# Symbols settings

Tags: c#, vb.net

When debugging the below following message appears in the immediate window. Can anyone explains to me easily what exactly does it mean and whether I should enable something related to this? Notice that I have already found some information on the internet but to be honest don't get it at all.

> 1. Use a debug build configuration or disable the debug option 'Enable Just My Code'.
> 2. Check the 'Symbols' settings under debugging options.Symbols for the module 'myapp.exe' were not loaded.
> 3. Use a debug build configuration or disable the debug option 'Enable Just My Code'.
> 4. Check the 'Symbols' settings under debugging options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sometimes, while you are debugging, you might want to look at only the code you have written and ignore other code, such as system calls. You can do this with Just My Code debugging. Just My Code hides non-user code so that it does not appear in the debugger windows. When you step, the debugger steps through any non-user code but does not stop in it.

Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.100).aspx) to read more about that topic in the documentation.

Comment: @Bugs I just checked and have already Just my code enabled. Why still see symbols then?

Comment: @Tony this is Archimedes answer not mine. I just edited. However I think to help you understand symbols have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx#symbols)